# Adding value to my Parse Table in Swift

Tags: database, swift, parse-platform

I want to add many rows at the same time to my data storage in Parse and I know that the column name and the inserting value should be typed as String but I don't get why this doesn't work . Can some one help me :)

```
let myClass = PFObject(className: "Testing")

for (var i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++){
    myClass["column \(i)"] = "\(i)"
}

myClass.saveInBackground()
```

Comment: I can't edit the question but the "myClass.saveInBackground()" is out of curly braces :)

Comment: I edited it out, but you can edit the question by selecting the edit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let myClass = PFObject(className: "Testing")

for (var i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++){
    myClass["column\(i)"] = "\(i)"
}

myClass.saveInBackground()
```

Comment: So, to clarify for future readers, the error was the space in the column name

Comment: in case that I had an array storing some data and I wanted to insert that into my data table and I wanted each one to be inserted at a new row then what should I do :) ?
@Moonwalkr